# [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; not working

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am using

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
}
```

for imagepicker
 and using

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in iPad to dismiss the picker.
also i tried using

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker;{
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

to dismiss the picker once it done the work.
BUt its not dimissing it. when i tap anywhere in the screen, than only it gets dismiss.

What i am doing wrong to dismiss the imagepicker?

Many thnkas

Comment: UiimagePickers are UIPopovers, not modal views.

Answer (score 0):

The view controller that should call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` should be the same one that called `presentModalViewController:animated:`

Answer (score 0):

May be you must not have set delegate of picker.Try this:-

```
picker.delegate = self;
```